# Java Object Join

Tags: java, oracle, join, jdbc

I have several queries in my application which perform cross schema join on oracle 11. Due to security reasons the schemas are being migrated to different DBs and I have to change the cross schema SQL queries into a different solution. The SQLs have 2-3 table joins and some WHERE conditions for filtering. Can someone suggest a solution to this ?

a. I was exploring the thought of querying the individual tables independently and then performing JOINS and filter in Java. I was exploring JDBCRowSet and FilterRowSet in Java for this, but these seem to have very basic join and filter support. Can someone suggest if most SQL JOINS and WHERE conditions can be translated to this ?

b. Moreover, some of the base queries (smaller queries that I have broken down from the larger cross schema join queries) will be retrieved through service calls to other applications. JDBCRowSet does not seem to be an elegant solution.

Note:- DBLink in Oracle is not an option due to database security reasons.